# SQL - Fill timestamp gaps and split rows to monitor complete days

Tags: mysql, datetime, split, fill

I have the following data set in a SQL DB:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9WMzE.png)

And that's what I want to achieve:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k750p.png)

This results in 4 tasks:

1. if an entry extends over one day, an entry should be set in the endTimestamp at 23:59:59 and on the following day a row that starts at 00:00:00 and ends with the original endTimestamp.

2. if there is a time gap between two statuses (StatusID), then this should be filled with the StatusID = 0.

3. if the status ends before 23:59:59 on one day, the remaining day up to 23:59:59 should be filled with status = 0.

4. if there are no entries for several days, these should be filled accordingly.

I would be very grateful if you could help me. I just can't find the correct solution.

I tried something using Datediff and Datetime2fromparts, but it doesn't really work.

Comment: Provide your data in well-formatted textual form only. See [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) and [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055) (#5 and #3).

Comment: How do you identify an entry? Is there a unique id for each entry? I doubt you're using `StateID` but if you do, that's not unique and it could make it harder to create a query.

Comment: Run `SHOW CREATE TABLE tablename;` and post the result [into your question edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/78049341/edit). And post any attempted query you've tried so far.